# Errors when trying out Confidential Transfer token extension on solana-test-validator

Tags: solana-test-validator, token-2022, token-extensions

I am getting errors when trying the confidential transfer token extension. Followed the instructions given in the [documentation](https://spl.solana.com/confidential-token/quickstart).

First tried it on the testnet, it worked fine till the create account step. The configure-confidential-transfer-account step was failing.

```
$ spl-token configure-confidential-transfer-account --address CXXUuUfmdPF9Yeu1koeT8cs7LQ4vqzT3N7kWDdDkNQcK
Error: Client(Error { request: Some(SendTransaction), kind: RpcError(RpcResponseError { code: -32002, message: "Transaction simulation failed: Attempt to load a program that does not exist", data: SendTransactionPreflightFailure(RpcSimulateTransactionResult { err: Some(ProgramAccountNotFound), logs: Some([]), accounts: None, units_consumed: Some(0), return_data: None }) }) })
```

According to [this page](https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/status), the confidential transfer functionality is not deployed yet on the mainnet. This might be the reason it was failing on the testnet. So I tried it on the local solana-test-validator. Made sure the version is up to date.

```
$ solana cluster-version
1.18.1
```

This time, the configure step worked fine. But I am getting InvalidInstructionData error at the next step.

```
$ spl-token deposit-confidential-tokens GzDVMsnbGvkN3Ry3fLg8KHz7apSNFc4XvuNT1c9aqLNN 100 --address 3619P1HKMXocexCmwj96UnAqLJ4H5J1iti5832q8XMPB
Depositing 100 confidential tokens
Error: Client(Error { request: Some(SendTransaction), kind: RpcError(RpcResponseError { code: -32002, message: "Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: invalid instruction data", data: SendTransactionPreflightFailure(RpcSimulateTransactionResult { err: Some(InstructionError(0, InvalidInstructionData)), logs: Some(["Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb invoke [1]", "Program log: ConfidentialTransferInstruction::Deposit", "Program log: Error: InvalidInstructionData", "Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb consumed 1179 of 200000 compute units", "Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb failed: invalid instruction data"]), accounts: None, units_consumed: Some(1179), return_data: None }) }) })
```

Made sure I minted tokens so that the account has it in balance.

```
$ spl-token accounts
Token                                         Balance
-----------------------------------------------------
GzDVMsnbGvkN3Ry3fLg8KHz7apSNFc4XvuNT1c9aqLNN  100
```

How can I test this extension? Is there any patch that should be applied for the confidential transfer functionality?

**Further research:**
I found the following code snippet [here](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/program-2022/src/extension/confidential_transfer/processor.rs#L1124).

```
ConfidentialTransferInstruction::Deposit => {
            msg!("ConfidentialTransferInstruction::Deposit");
            #[cfg(feature = "zk-ops")]
            {
                let data = decode_instruction_data::<DepositInstructionData>(input)?;
                process_deposit(program_id, accounts, data.amount.into(), data.decimals)
            }
            #[cfg(not(feature = "zk-ops"))]
            Err(ProgramError::InvalidInstructionData)
        }
```

The error might be due to this but I was getting ProofGeneration error for the following command. This might be due to there being no confidential tokens deposited so I am not sure.

```
$ spl-token withdraw-confidential-tokens GzDVMsnbGvkN3Ry3fLg8KHz7apSNFc4XvuNT1c9aqLNN 100 --address 3619P1HKMXocexCmwj96UnAqLJ4H5J1iti5832q8XMPB
Withdrawing 100 confidential tokens
Error: ProofGeneration
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to build and deploy your own version of token-2022 with the zk-ops enabled since the default version that comes with the test validator does not include it.

To do that, you'll need to check out the SPL repo, go to https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/token/program-2022 and then build using:

```
cargo build-sbf
```

After that, you can override token-2022 in your test validator by running:

```
solana-test-validator -r --bpf-program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb \
  path/to/your/solana-program-library/target/deploy/spl_token_2022.so
```